# how to save multiple tables record in a single datagridview in visual studio using oracle database

Tags: vb.net, oracle

```
Private Sub DGVemploie_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVemploie.CellContentClick
        ouvrircnx()
        cmd = New OracleCommand("SELECT *FROM salle s,  FULL JOIN  groupe g ON s.codesalle = g.codegroupe ", cnx)
        da = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds, "salle")
        DGVemploie.DataSource = ds.Tables("salle,groupe")
        fermercnx()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to pull 2 tables into one Datatable? Maybe [Union All](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_union.asp) is what you're looking for...

Comment: @Mr.Tripodi   i want to save 3 tables and fill them in one datagrid view using  vb.net and oracle datebase

Comment: That is a bit vague explanation. 'save 3 tables' for example, do these tables exist already? You want to update the rows? you want to insert rows? Do they have the same schema? It's unclear what youre trying to do

Comment: Do the tables have the same schema? Have you tried UNION ALL? Thinking thats what you want to do

Comment: @ Mr.Tripodi yes they exist in my database i want to fill them in data grid i tried to use this  one SELECT s.codesalle,s.nombloc||s.numbloc||s.numetage as NOMSALLECOMPLET,codegroupe,niveau||specialite||numgroupe as NOMGROUPECOMPLET

Comment: the table are in the same database

Comment: Hey, sorry, I guess you're not understanding. Are all the column names, types and sizes identical on all the tables?

Comment: yes i don't know how to fill them in datagrid with vb.net

Comment: Are all the columns in the same order in all tables?

Answer (score 0):

Change the command from this:

```
"SELECT *FROM salle s,  FULL JOIN  groupe g ON s.codesalle = g.codegroupe "
```

To this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TABLE2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TABLE3
```

*Replace the table names with your actual table names.

Comment: Additionally you may be able to do something like this `SELECT *,'1' As TableID FROM TABLE1 UNION ALL SELECT *,'2' As TableID FROM TABLE2 UNION ALL SELECT *,'3' As TableID FROM TABLE3` which in theory should give you a column in your result that you know which table the rows are from. It is also considered better practice to type out all column names rather than use wildcard '*'

Comment: and how  i can fill them in datagrid in vb.net?

Comment: it looks like you had that worked out... i am assuming you dont understand your code?